# How to play Live Streaming video in Android

Tags: android, streaming, live, android-video-player

In my project I have a requirement to play live streaming video. I have seen many comments that "live streaming is supported only from 3.0" so that I have to use emulator 3.0.  But it does not play.  Can anybody help for me.. This is my code:

```
String SrcPath="http://akamedia2.lsops.net/live/smil:cnbc_en.smil/playlist.m3u8";
myVideoView = new VideoView(this);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
setContentView(myVideoView);
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return false;
    }
});
myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         myVideoView.start();
    }
});
```

The following logcat for this:

```
Generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001002_00000000 [ 87 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x477ba6f0:0x477ba8a8] in 606126 ns
V/TLINE   (  360): new: android.text.TextLine@40643358
D/MediaPlayer(  360): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
I/ActivityManager(   65): Displayed com.leadapps.android/.LivestreamTest: +1s834ms
D/MediaPlayer(  360): getMetadata
E/MediaPlayerService(   33): getMetadata failed -38
I/LiveSession(   33): onConnect 'http://akamedia2.lsops.net/live/smil:cnbc_en.smil/playlist.m3u8'
I/NuHTTPDataSource(   33): connect to akamedia2.lsops.net:80/live/smil:cnbc_en.smil/playlist.m3u8 @0
D/dalvikvm(  144): GC_EXPLICIT freed 929K, 13% free 14528K/16583K, paused 3ms+3ms
I/NuHTTPDataSource(   33): connect to akamedia2.lsops.net:80/live/smil:cnbc_en.smil/chunklist-b33000.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1036169757 @0
I/NuHTTPDataSource(   33): connect to akamedia2.lsops.net:80/live/smil:cnbc_en.smil/media-b33000_7023.aac?wowzasessionid=1036169757 @0
E/LiveSession(   33): This doesn't look like a transport stream...
I/LiveSession(   33): Retrying with a different bandwidth stream.
I/NuHTTPDataSource(   33): connect to akamedia2.lsops.net:80/live/smil:cnbc_en.smil/chunklist-b120000.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1036169757 @0
I/NuHTTPDataSource(   33): connect to akamedia2.lsops.net:80/live/smil:cnbc_en.smil/media-b120000_7092.ts?wowzasessionid=1036169757 @0
D/dalvikvm(  192): GC_EXPLICIT freed 148K, 5% free 6720K/7047K, paused 4ms+4ms
I/NuHTTPDataSource(   33): connect to akamedia2.lsops.net:80/live/smil:cnbc_en.smil/media-b120000_7093.ts?wowzasessionid=1036169757 @0
I/avc_utils(   33): found AVC codec config (480 x 256, Baseline-profile level 3.0)
I/ESQueue (   33): found AAC codec config (24000 Hz, 1 channels)
F/ACodec  (   33): frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp:1594 CHECK_EQ( omx->allocateNode(componentName.c_str(), observer, &node),(status_t)OK) failed: -2147483648 vs. 0
I/DEBUG   (   31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:3.0/HONEYCOMB/104254:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   31): pid: 33, tid: 371  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r0 deadbaad  r1 0000000c  r2 00000027  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r4 00000080  r5 aff46658  r6 40706d3c  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r8 a801c211  r9 00013000  10 00100000  fp 00000001
I/DEBUG   (   31):  ip ffffffff  sp 407068e0  lr aff193e9  pc aff15f58  cpsr 00000030
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #00  pc 00015f58  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #01  pc 00001466  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert)
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #02  pc 00008d90  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so (_ZN7android3OMX18CallbackDispatcherC1EPNS_15OMXNodeInstanceE)
I/DEBUG   (   31): 
I/DEBUG   (   31): libc base address: aff00000
I/DEBUG   (   31): 
I/DEBUG   (   31): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   31): aff15f38 68241c23 d1fb2c00 68dae027 d0042a00 
I/DEBUG   (   31): aff15f48 20014d18 6028447d 48174790 24802227 
I/DEBUG   (   31): aff15f58 f7f57002 2106ea02 eb6ef7f6 0563aa01 
I/DEBUG   (   31): aff15f68 60932100 91016051 1c112006 eed4f7f5 
I/DEBUG   (   31): aff15f78 2200a905 f7f52002 f7f5eee0 2106e9ee 
I/DEBUG   (   31): 
I/DEBUG   (   31): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   31): aff193c8 b0834a0d 589c447b 26009001 686768a5 
I/DEBUG   (   31): aff193d8 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901 
I/DEBUG   (   31): aff193e8 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee 
I/DEBUG   (   31): aff193f8 bdf01c30 00028168 ffffff8c 1c0fb5f0 
I/DEBUG   (   31): aff19408 43551c3d a904b087 1c16ac01 604d9004 
I/DEBUG   (   31): 
I/DEBUG   (   31): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068a0  00100000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068a4  0000035f  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068a8  aff416f0  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068ac  aff41690  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068b0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068b4  aff193e9  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068b8  00000009  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068bc  aff18459  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068c0  afc01199  /system/lib/liblog.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068c4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068c8  aff46658  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068cc  40706d3c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068d0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068d4  aff186e7  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068d8  df002777  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068dc  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   (   31): #00 407068e0  407068dc  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068e4  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068e8  a2c386b7  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068ec  00000007  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068f0  40706914  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068f4  fffffbdf  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068f8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407068fc  a2c386b7  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706900  00000080  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706904  afc01469  /system/lib/liblog.so
I/DEBUG   (   31): #01 40706908  a2c386b7  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     4070690c  afc01469  /system/lib/liblog.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706910  40706d2c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706914  6d617266  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706918  726f7765  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     4070691c  622f736b  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706920  2f657361  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706924  6964656d  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706928  696c2f61  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     4070692c  61747362  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706930  72666567  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706934  74686769  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706938  6f43412f  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     4070693c  2e636564  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706940  3a707063  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706944  34393531  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706948  45484320  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     4070694c  455f4b43  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706950  6f202851  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706954  3e2d786d  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706958  6f6c6c61  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     4070695c  65746163  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706960  65646f4e  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706964  6d6f6328  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706968  656e6f70  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     4070696c  614e746e  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706970  632e656d  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706974  7274735f  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706978  202c2928  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     4070697c  6573626f  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706980  72657672  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706984  6e26202c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706988  2965646f  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     4070698c  7473282c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706990  73757461  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706994  4f29745f  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706998  6620294b  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     4070699c  656c6961  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069a0  2d203a64  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069a4  37343132  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069a8  36333834  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069ac  76203834  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069b0  30202e73  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069b4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069b8  40706a40  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069bc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069c0  ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069c4  b00094e8  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069c8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069cc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069d0  a801c211  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069d4  407069d4  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069d8  b00053d1  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069dc  b000a04c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069e0  b000a087  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069e4  b000a34b  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069e8  0000003b  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069ec  40706a34  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069f0  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069f4  38303131  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069f8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     407069fc  80008e83  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a00  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a04  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a08  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a0c  40706b80  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a10  00000070  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a14  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a18  40706aa8  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a1c  000000c0  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a20  b000952c  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a24  00000454  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a28  40706a8c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a2c  b0004c35  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a30  b0007120  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a34  b0006bb8  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a38  00000454  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a3c  a300b042  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a40  00000018  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a44  40706b80  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a48  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a4c  8000595b  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a50  40706b80  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a54  40706a9c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a58  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a5c  a2c25f9d  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a60  ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a64  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a68  4089501b  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a6c  b00094e8  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a70  a78e7cd8  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a74  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a78  a78e7cd8  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a7c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a80  000005f8  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a84  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a88  0001c2c0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a8c  7379732f  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a90  2f6d6574  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a94  2f62696c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a98  7362696c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706a9c  65676174  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706aa0  67697266  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706aa4  77687468  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706aa8  006f732e  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706aac  afb04a3c  /system/lib/libcutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ab0  0000f438  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ab4  40706afc  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ab8  00000009  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706abc  a8015049  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ac0  0000f428  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ac4  0000f438  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ac8  00000009  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706acc  a8015165  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ad0  0000f3d8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ad4  40706afc  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ad8  fffffffc  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706adc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ae0  40706afc  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ae4  a81147b5  /system/lib/libbinder.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ae8  40706c48  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706aec  a811a575  /system/lib/libbinder.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706af0  00000030  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706af4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706af8  00024230  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706afc  0000f3d8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b00  40706b18  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b04  40706c48  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b08  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b0c  40009028  /dev/binder
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b10  40009038  /dev/binder
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b14  a811a5a1  /system/lib/libbinder.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b18  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b1c  a801c211  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b20  40706c48  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b24  00000010  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b28  40009028  /dev/binder
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b2c  a811a5fb  /system/lib/libbinder.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b30  40009038  /dev/binder
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b34  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b38  ffffff20  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b3c  a8123204  /system/lib/libbinder.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b40  000241d0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b44  a81165b7  /system/lib/libbinder.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b48  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b4c  a81164c1  /system/lib/libbinder.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b50  000241d0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b54  a8123204  /system/lib/libbinder.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b58  40706c78  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b5c  000241d0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b60  00024200  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b64  40706c48  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b68  00000060  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b6c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b70  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b74  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b78  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b7c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b80  000003e8  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b84  00000010  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b88  00000004  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b8c  40009028  /dev/binder
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b90  40009038  /dev/binder
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b94  4ab3df53  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b98  00000009  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706b9c  0000f43c  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ba0  ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ba4  40706bfc  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ba8  a801c211  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bac  afb04a3c  /system/lib/libcutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bb0  0000f438  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bb4  40706bfc  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bb8  0000003b  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bbc  0000003b  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bc0  b000a04c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bc4  a801c211  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bc8  00013000  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bcc  00100000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bd0  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bd4  b00120d9  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bd8  40706c2c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bdc  b0005405  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706be0  b00053d1  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706be4  00000006  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706be8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bec  aff10ed4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bf0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bf4  aff10ed4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bf8  00000033  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706bfc  000245d8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c00  000001b4  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c04  c0000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c08  a801c211  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c0c  00013000  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c10  00100000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c14  aff1402b  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c18  000001b4  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c1c  c0000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c20  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c24  aff10ed4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c28  000000da  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c2c  00007a08  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c30  000001b4  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c34  c0000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c38  a801c211  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c3c  00013000  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c40  00100000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c44  aff12d45  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c48  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c4c  aff10ed4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c50  00000013  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c54  000245a8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c58  300001b4  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c5c  4ab3df53  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c60  a801c211  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c64  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c68  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c6c  aff10ed4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c70  00000013  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c74  000245d0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c78  000001b4  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c7c  c0000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c80  a801c211  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c84  00013000  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c88  00100000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c8c  aff1402b  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c90  7fffffff  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c94  00000020  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c98  a801c211  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706c9c  00013000  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ca0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ca4  aff10ed4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ca8  000245c8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cac  000245c8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cb0  00000010  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cb4  000000a0  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cb8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cbc  aff10ed4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cc0  000245c8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cc4  000245c8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cc8  000000a8  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ccc  000000c0  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cd0  a801c211  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cd4  00013000  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cd8  00100000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cdc  aff14461  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ce0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ce4  000245d0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706ce8  00000011  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cec  000245a8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cf0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cf4  a801c211  /system/lib/libutils.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cf8  00013000  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706cfc  00100000  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706d00  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706d04  0002465f  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706d08  40706d3c  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706d0c  8000774b  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706d10  40706d48  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706d14  4ab3df53  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706d18  000245a8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706d1c  a3008d95  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706d20  40706d48  
I/DEBUG   (   31):     40706d24  a2b4d3a3  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
W/AudioSystem(   65): AudioPolicyService server died!
W/AudioSystem(  360): AudioFlinger server died!
W/IMediaDeathNotifier(  360): media server died
E/MediaPlayer(  360): error (100, 0)
E/MediaPlayer(  360): Error (100,0)
D/VideoView(  360): Error: 100,0
I/ee      (  360): ==============100
W/AudioSystem(  131): AudioFlinger server died!
W/AudioSystem(  131): AudioPolicyService server died!
I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.camera' died
I/ServiceManager(   28): service 'media.audio_policy' died
I/BootReceiver(   65): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
D/dalvikvm(  360): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 62K, 3% free 6407K/6599K, paused 124ms
```

Comment: Please share how you play live streaming chanels?

Answer (score 0):

```
 String SrcPath="http://akamedia2.lsops.net/live/smil:cnbc_en.smil/playlist.m3u8";
        myVideoView = new VideoView(this);
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
        setContentView(myVideoView);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
```

Remove this line.

```
myVideoView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Thank you for giving response for my question , but it does not work for me. And There is no Change in logcat....

Answer (score 0):

According to some threads, you should use httplive:// scheme for version 2.3 and 3.0 and the http:// scheme for 3.0+: [How to play m3u8 on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198995/how-to-play-m3u8-on-android)

It worked on my 2.3 device but I'm not sure if it wold work on an emulator. Moreover, I made it work using the m3u8 test URI ( http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8 ) of apple. I can't still make it work using the my own URI.