# Live tv channel streaming api

Tags: android, live-streaming

There are a lot of live tv apps available in Android market.I also want to make such an application. But I don't know from where I will get the api for live tv streaming. YouTube provides a few number of channels as live. There is no Malayalam and Hindi channels. But I want these types of channels also.

Is there any solution to this problem? Please provide me some help.I have searched a lot but didn't get any solution.

I have another doubt can we implement a server for live channel broadcast and if so how?

Comment: somw help-ful links 
http://www.livestream.com/platform/developer

https://code.google.com/p/m3-stream/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/servestream/

https://code.google.com/p/mizuu-for-phones/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595204/how-to-play-live-streaming-video-in-android