# live streaming TV channels in android

Tags: android, live-streaming

Hello i am new android developer. And I don't know about Live Streaming Hindi TV channels. I find on net but not get perfect idea.

Can anybody give me idea about how android works with live Streaming channels.

THanks in advance.
Dimple

Comment: Do you want to stream live videos?

Comment: i need to create like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spb.tv.digivive.free&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zcGIudHYuZGlnaXZpdmUuZnJlZSJd this app. I am very stuck where to start and how to develop?

Comment: your referenced app has been deleted from the store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VideoView for this. Try following:

```
String LINK = "type_here_the_link";
setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

For more info, please see this: [how to play video from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620049/how-to-play-video-from-url)

Comment: Some helpful links: http://www.livestream.com/platform/developer https://code.google.com/p/m3-stream/ http://sourceforge.net/projects/servestream/ https://code.google.com/p/mizuu-for-phones/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595204/how-to-play-live-streaming-video-in-android

Comment: Thanks for this code and can you guide me from where i find all channel links to play?

Comment: Nop.. i am finding all TV channels URL

Comment: The following are the samples of live streaming videos, you can check it for development. http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbopgear1.html http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbopgear2.html http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbopgear3.html http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbopgear4.html http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbopall.html

Comment: Check if you can play any video as live streaming from above links, if you succeed in it, then you can anytime change the url to your live tv channel url.

Comment: In all these channels i get sorry this video can not be played.

Comment: Super simple solution for a good quick starting point. If some on is beginner like me thank to add is that you can add this code in MainActivity.java file in onCreate and commentout setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer) if you dont have it.