# Android does not display m3u8 format in videoview, only sound

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

```
I didn't use a real device, I was working on emulator. (Problem Solved)
```

I am developing a live stream video application. I have so many live stream URLs which have *.m3u8 postfix.

When I start the app, I can hear only sound but no video displaying. Video display area is always dark.

I am waiting for your helpful suggestions to solve my problem.

Regards.

Some of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    String videourl = "URL/playlist.m3u8";
    VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_View);

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Buffering video...", true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        PlayVideo();
    }

    private void PlayVideo() {
        try {
            getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

            Uri video = Uri.parse(videourl);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.setVideoURI(video);
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    videoView.start();

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Video Play Error :" + e.toString());
            finish();
        }

    }

}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_View"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
        </VideoView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing this? `getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);`

Comment: Yeah, and I tried so many pixel formats. But not displaying video

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. I just tried using this stream and it works fine: http://208.75.229.59:1935/1tv/smil:1tvmulti.smil/playlist.m3u8 Make sure your content meets the requirements here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Is it work on emulator, did you try ?

Comment: It works on my device. Video streaming on emulator is usually very poor as video often uses hardware acceleration that your emulator does not have. Try and test on a real device.

Comment: Already tried. Really thanks for your suggestions. I will try diffent devices about 10 mins later.