# Facing lag when opening Fragment which plays video

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview

I'm having a hard time getting the desired performance while loading a video in a Fragment using AsyncTask.

I think Im tying up the UI thread, but I don't understand where, and I don't see a memory leak.
I have tried executing  the `AyncTask` from `onAttach()`, `OnCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, and `setUserVisibleHint()`

I have also tried setting and using `onPreparedListener()`

In all these attempts I'm still seeing a performance lag when the `VideoFragment` lifecycle gets called. By lag I don't mean connectivity since Im loading the video from the `raw` folder.

[image]

So, as it transitions from `IntroFragment` to `DetailsFragment`, `VideoFragment`'s lifecycle (onAttach,onCreate,onCreateView, etc) fires off, and this is where I see the "lag" right before `DetailsFragment` becomes visible.

**FragmentsHolder**

```
public abstract class FragmentsHolder extends FragmentActivity{

   @Override
    final protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPagerAdapter = new PagerIntroAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
 }
}
```

**FirstSequence**

```
public class FirstSequence extends FragmentsHolder {

@Override
public void init(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    addSlide(IntroFragment.newInstance("First String","Second String",
            R.drawable.intro_fragment_drawable, 0, 0, 0, Color.parseColor("#4798af"), 1));
    addSlide(DetailsFragment.newInstance("First Details String","Second Details String",
            R.drawable.details_fragment_drawable, 0, 0, 0, Color.parseColor("#4798af"), 1));
    addSlide(FourImagesFragment.newInstance("Title String","Instruction String", R.drawable.image_1, R.drawable.image_2, R.drawable.image_3, 
            R.drawable.image_4, Color.parseColor("#4798af"), 1));
    addSlide(VideoFragment.newInstance(R.raw.my_video,"Video title string","Video subtitle string",
            0, 0, 0, 0, Color.parseColor("#4798af"), 1));
```

**VideoFragment**

```
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment{
   View hackyView;
   private Handler subt_text;
   private static final String ARG_VIDEO_TO_LOAD = "videotoload";
   ...

 public static VideoFragment newInstance(int videoToLoad, String title, String subTitle,int imageDrawable1,int imageDrawable2,int imageDrawable3,int imageDrawable4,int bgColor, int progressCounter){

  VideoFragment sampleSlide = new VideoFragment();

  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putInt(ARG_VIDEO_TO_LOAD,videoToLoad);
  ...

  return sampleSlide;

 }

private int videoToLoad, ....;
private String title, ...;

 @Override
 public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    System.out.println("VideoFragment OnAttach ");
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //get args
    if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().size() != 0) {
    videoToLoad = getArguments().getInt(ARG_VIDEO_TO_LOAD);
    ...
    }
    System.out.println("VideoFragment OnCreate ");
   }

 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);
  hackyView = v;
  //new loadVideoTask().execute();
  System.out.println("VideoFragment OnCreateView ");
  return vView;
 } 

 @Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
 super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
   if(isVisibleToUser){
   new loadVideoTask().execute(); 
   }else {

   }
 }

 private class loadVideoTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

 ProgressDialog pDialog;

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {

    System.out.println("AsyncTask load onPreExecute ");
    DialogMessage = "Loading Video";
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage(DialogMessage);
    pDialog.show();
 }

 @Override
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

    slideUpAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_up);
    cv1 = (CardView) hackyView.findViewById(R.id.cv1);
    //Initialize the rest of the Views, animations, etc
    ...
    return hackyView;
 }  

 protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    //process result load video
    loadVideo();
    pDialog.dismiss();
 }
}  

private void loadVideo() {
  subt_text = new Handler();
  vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
  vid.requestFocus();
  vid.seekTo(seekto);
  //set all views
 }

}
```

I've read numerous questions on fragments, their life cycles, etc, but I still can't figure out how do I use those answers to help me understand what Im doing wrong in my implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the "lag" I was seeing in transitioning between fragments, which was a black screen flicker, is solved by adding..

```
<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px" />
```

to fragment's parent activity's xml. In my case the `FragmentHolder`'s xml.
I found the answer as well more links explaining why this works here [VideoView inside fragment causes black screen flicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717906/videoview-inside-fragment-causes-black-screen-flicking)

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Android 5.1.